# how to turn off SQLite autoindex feature?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

My **Android** application uses **SQLite** and **ORMLite** to work with data. There is need to insert a big amount of data at one time and I want to make this faster than it is for this moment. For that I want to drop indexes then insert data and then recreate indexes.

**Problem:**
is when application creates database - SQLite adds indexes to some fields in db automatically. They called `sqlite_autoindex_%TableName%%ColumnName%_1`

my ORM entites have fields marked to be indexed in db. And after creating tables ORMLite creates that indexes. SQLIte auto indexes dublicates indexes, created by ORMLIte so I need to configure SQLite to turn autoindexes off. 
I have found that this feature turns off with query "`PRAGMA automatic_index = false;`" So i overrided method of `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`:

```
@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = super.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA automatic_index = false;");
    return db;
}
```

That didn't help. Wrong place for query?
Please help

Comment: What's your schema? IIRC SQLite requires UNIQUE columns to be indexed, and will automatically create indexes for them. `PRAGMA automatic_index` refers to [an unrelated feature where SQLite will create a temporary index while evaluating a query](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#autoindex)

Comment: I don't know how to get schema info. I think it's  the main sqlite schema. Auto indexed are not temporary. I have opened my db in navicat and see that indexes have type 'normal'.

Comment: made a mistake :( indexes called sqlite_autoindex_%TableName%_1 without column name. Navicat shows that they do not have any columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite automatically creates indexes for column in PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints.
(The only exception is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.)
These cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike what's near to always stated, you can go without getting automatic indexes generated, which may significantly reduce a DB size (after own experience).

After my own experience, you got `sqlite_autoindex_"table_name"_N` when you have tables with "ROWID", which is the default. If you design a table using `WITHOUT ROWID` [[synax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)], there is no more automatic index (along to no more "ROWID") for that table.

However, note the following [[source](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)]:

- `WITHOUT ROWID` tables, can't use `AUTOINCREMENT`;
- `WITHOUT ROWID` tables, must have a `PRIMARY KEY` (and for this, your best bet is to use a prefix of the table rows);
- `WITHOUT ROWID` tables behave differently with regards to PK values: there use to be a bug in SQLite, letting it accept `NULL` values fro primary keys (it was hence diverging from the standard). Later, when `WITHOUT ROWID` was added, it was decided that it will also enforce the standard semantic which disallows `NULL` for primary keys.

Additionally, after my own experience, if there is any `UNIQUE` constraint which does not have the PK as a prefix, the `sqlite_autoindex_"table_name"_N` will still be generated (one have to imagine what an implementation could be, to guess why it is so).

As a side note to help avoid confusion with another use of the term “automatic index” with SQLite, note this [[source](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)] :

> Do not confuse automatic indexes with the internal indexes (having names like "sqlite_autoindex_table_N") that are sometimes created to implement a PRIMARY KEY constraint or UNIQUE constraint. The automatic indexes described here exist only for the duration of a single query, are never persisted to disk, and are only visible to a single database connection. Internal indexes are part of the implementation of PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints, are long-lasting and persisted to disk, and are visible to all database connections. **The term "autoindex" appears in the names of internal indexes for legacy reasons and does not indicate that internal indexes and automatic indexes are related.**

Formally, with SQLite, automatic index, really means something else. This confusion does not help, one must have it in mind when reading the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me in Ormlite and Sqlcipher:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(...);
database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA automatic_index = 0");
```